# DRAM monitoring tool

Tags: performance, memory

Is there any tool that can shows how much memory is used in each DRAM? Like 40% is used in DRAM1, 20% is used in DRAM2.

The concept is similar to [PageFileUsageMonitor](http://www.standards.com/ThisAndThat/PageFileUsageMonitor.html). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work like that.  To the OS, RAM is RAM.  2x2GB chips is no different than 4x1GB chips.  Plus, why does it matter to know which physical chip is storing a certain amount of data?  I'm not sure how that information would even be useful.

If you're curious about RAM usage, the Windows 7 task manager really provides a good overview of how much RAM you have, how much is allocated, how much is cache, and how much is available vs. actually free.

Comment: Well said, the Resource Monitor provides even more detail.